# understanding SVM-light output (matlab)

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

I am using `SVM-light` on matlab, and I am interested in extracting the result `W` myself (instead on using the built in `predict` function). 
The result is a struct with

- `model.supvec`, the support vectors, but augmented with an all zero vector (that I have no idea why it is good for).
- `model.a` and `model.alpha` seems like the coefficients are in `model.a`, so I have no idea what is stored in `model.alpha`.
- `model.index`, which I understood as keeping the indexes of the support vector, i.e. what coefficient goes with what support vector, but there is also a lot of numbers besides the `1:num(suuport vectors)` (and sometimes I get that one index appears twice but once with coefficient zero).

All in all, I can't figure out half of it (but its working suspiciously well so far). Anyone has any idea what all this data means?